# using the exist flag to overwrite existing file

Tags: racket

I'm currently reading the FileSystem part of the racket documentation, I'm unable to figure out how to use the exist flag, here is what I have written:

```
(define (write-file file data) 
  (with-output-to-file file 
    (lambda () 
      (write data))
    #:exists (or/c 'error 'append 'update 'can-update 'replace 'truncate 'must-truncate 'truncate/replace)))))
```

the documentation provided no example usage, I'm one of those who learns best via examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
(or/c 'error 'append 'update 'can-update 'replace 
      'truncate 'must-truncate 'truncate/replace)))))
```

means you need to choose one of the flags.

For example:

```
 (define (write-file file data) 
   (with-output-to-file file 
     (lambda () 
       (write data))
     #:exists 'replace))
```

The Guide is full of examples: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/ports.html

Update:

This is my attempt to explain how to read the documentation.
The first part of the blue box contains:

```
(open-output-file path               
     [  #:mode mode-flag                 
        #:exists exists-flag])      →       output-port?
```

It means that the function `open-output-file` takes one argument `path`
and returns an `output-port`.

This `(open-output-file "foo.txt")` will open the file and return a port.
The square brackets signal optional arguments. For example:
`(open-output-file "foo.txt" #:mode 'binary)` will open the file in binary mode.

The docs says `#:mode mode-flag` so what comes after `#:mode` must be a legal `mode-flag`. Further down in the blue box it says:

```
  mode-flag   : (or/c 'binary 'text) = 'binary
```

this means that the `mode-flag` can be either `'binary` or `'text`.

Note that the `path` argument is also explained:

```
  path        : path-string?
```

This means that one must use a value for which `path-string?` will return true.
To see what that means click on `path-string?` and read about path strings.

The last part is the list of `exists-flag`s. The `or/c` means that we must use of the flags at a time.

```
  exists-flag : (or/c 'error 'append 'update 'can-update
                      'replace 'truncate 'must-truncate 'truncate/replace)
```

Note also that the documentation is in two parts: a reference and a guide. There are more examples in the Guide, so check it out.

Comment: it was that simple.. how did you figure this out ? I'm not learning a whole lot from the documentation. Edit: jeez I hadn't even .. seen those there.. thank you!! i feel really stupid :D

Comment: When you have used the docs for a while, you learn what the blue boxes mean. I have added an explanation of the blue box.

Comment: Further info on how to read the documentation is here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/notation.html